# Parsing text file to Tree Java

Tags: java

Working on an assignment where we are required to parse a text file and use that information to draw a tree. The text file is setup like so:

```
<1 E>
  <2 N>
    <4 A>
      <7 L>
        <12 K>
        </12> 
      </7> 
    </4> 
    <5 J>
      <8 H>
      </8> 
      <9 I>
      </9> 
    </5> 
  </2> 
  <3 F>
    <6 G>
      <10 0>
        <13 B>
        </13> 
      </10> 
      <11 C>
        <14 D>
        </14> 
        <15 M>
        </15> 
      </11> 
    </6> 
  </3> 
</1>
```

Where E is the root and every node listed before  is a child of E. The number is each node's unique identifier.

We've already set up our GUI and we just need to be able to parse this text file. At first we thought that the unique ID numbers would allow us to construct the tree, but after looking at it we realized that approach would only work for binary trees. The way the text file is structured leads us to believe that there is some recursive approach but we can't see it. We also don't know what kind of object we want to put the parsed tree information into before we can draw it.

Edit: Though we should include code of what we were trying to do before. We're pretty sure we're completely on the wrong track but w/e.

```
public String recurseTree(Node parent, int depth, File file) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        String line = "";
        if(fileScan.hasNext())
        {
            line = fileScan.nextLine();
        }

        while(!(line.isEmpty()))
        {
            System.out.println(line);

            int tabs = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
            {
                if(line.substring(i, i+1).equals("\t"))
                    tabs++;

            }
            if(tabs < depth)
                break;
            Node node = new Node(line);
            if(tabs >= depth)
            {
                if(parent != null)
                {
                    //System.out.println(parent.toString());
                }
                line = recurseTree(node, tabs, file);
            }

        }
        //System.out.println(line);
        return line;
```

This is our node class

```
private class Node
    {
        Node parent;
        Set<Node> children;
        String name;

        public Node()
        {
            this.parent = null;
            this.name = null;
            this.children = new HashSet();
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void setParent(Node parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
        }
        public void addChild(Node child)
        {
            children.add(child);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To determine the type of object you want to store data in, first try to get a concrete handle on what the data is, then you can design an object to meet those requirements. You have:

- A tree of data with one root node.
- Each node can have more than one child.
- Each node has a numeric ID and a string name.

So, a direct translation is straightforward:

```
class TreeNode {
   List<TreeNode> children; // each node can have more than one child
   int id; // each node has a numeric ID
   String name; // each node has a string name
}
```

And of course, elsewhere:

```
TreeNode root; // the single root node.
```

(Edit: Note that a `Set<TreeNode>` can be used to store children as well; in your case, it's essentially the same. I just default to `List` for reasons that are not particularly relevant here.)

The next step is to determine what functions you need to be able to perform:

- Need to be able to create a new node, given an ID and a name.
- Need to be able to add a child to an existing node.
- Need to be able to get a node's ID and name.
- Need to be able to get a node's children.

I'm not going to do your work for you, of course, so I am not going to give you code for that -- but the point is, determine your requirements first, then you can design the code to match.

At this point you will have a workable `TreeNode` data structure to use. *Now* you are ready to concentrate on loading data from a file. For this, it's a similar process to the above: Determine your requirements, then implement.

First I'd start by trying to concretely identify the structure of your input file:

- A node starts with `<ID NAME>`.
- Any number of child nodes may be present after the node start.
- A node ends with `</ID>`.

In other words:

```
NODE = <id name> NODE* </id>
```

Now try to think how you would construct a tree from that:

- Read an `<ID NAME>` token and construct a new `TreeNode` from it.
- Read any inner nodes and add them as children, using these same steps.
- Stop when `</ID>` is read.

This lends itself well to a recursive approach, which I believe you will be able to work out once you have your general `TreeNode` data structure implemented and your file format concretely described.

You may be surprised to note, by the way (just quickly commenting on the code you just posted) that at no point during the loading of the file, as described above, do you need to track the depth of the tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. We already have a node class written. We were also thinking that we would create a linked list to represent the tree. Our code for our node class is:

Comment: A linked list is for a list. A tree is generally not a list (although each node may have a *list* of children). Your data structure should reflect the nature of your data. Each node should contain a list of references to all child nodes, and the only thing you need to store externally is the root node (all children can ultimately be accessed via the root).

Comment: @user3430902 Please for the love of g*d don't try pasting your code in a comment. At minimum use http://pastebin.com/ or https://ideone.com/.

Comment: That sounds like a linked list to me. We thought you could have the head be the root of the tree, then each node would contain a set of its children.

Comment: It's close. A linked list is essentially a tree where each node can have *no more than one child*. A linked list, for example, has the concept of the Nth item in the list. A tree does not have that concept. *You* have a data structure where each node can have *more than one* child, and so a linked list is not sufficient. Does that make sense? A data structure where each item has more than one "next" item isn't a linked list.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. We're still back at the beginning of what data structure to use then. We understand the concepts of the nodes, but I guess we don't know how to link them all up. Maybe a map, but we don't know what your key set would be.

Comment: Look at the `TreeNode` example class I posted. That's precisely what your nodes need to be: A node, with an ID and a name, and a list of children. Nothing more. The only built-in Java containers you'd need here are a `List` (either a `LinkedList` or an `ArrayList`) of children for each node. Your data structure is a tree; and *you* are implementing it -- the tree is all you. Each of your node objects holds its own list of children, and you hold onto a reference to the root node -- this is all it takes to store your data. I think you are over-thinking this. :)

Comment: I notice you use a `Set` for child nodes rather than a `List`. This is a perfectly reasonable alternative, by the way.

Comment: I'd have to agree with the overthinking aspect.  Thanks for all your help Jason, gunna let this one marinade for a few hours and come back.